# Does mremap "initialize" memory on growth?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

If I've **mmap**() some ***PRIVATE*** and ***ANONYMOUS*** pages and then extend them with **mremap**(), does the new space also get initialized to zeroes?

I've tried reading the code for mremap (**mm/mremap.c**) in the linux source but it requires some domain-specific knowledge that I don't currently have (vma_###  stuff). Not even sure that's the right place to look...

But, from what I've gathered I *think* that **mremap**()ed memory would be cleared, is this correct?

Allocation is done like this

```
list = mmap(NULL, newSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)
```

and then remap is done like this

```
newList = mremap(list, oldSize, newSize, MREMAP_MAYMOVE)
```

Ah, and last, it's a ***Linux*** specific question, running a recent kernel (>=2.6.28) and libc (>= 2.11.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous pages are copy-on-write mappings of the universal zero page. They always have been (on every system, not just Linux, that offers anonymous mappings) and always will be. When `mremap` (or `brk`) extends an anonymous mapping, you get new anonymous (zero) pages. There is no need to initialize them yourself.

Comment: Yep. Anything but zero pages would be a security hole as well.

Comment: You are mistaken about copy-on-write mappings of the universal zero page. At least on Linux this is not how `mmap()` works. You get physical pages mapped on the first access to the mapped memory, and this is the kernel page fault handler that zeroes the physical page and maps it. No universal zero page involved.

Comment: Are you sure? Certainly for read-only anonymous mappings it doesn't make a physical page for each page. What I said is definitely true in a sense if you enable merging of duplicate pages, but I may be wrong in general; I haven't RTFS'd or tested it.

Comment: It's not important where the zeroing comes from for this question, only that it is cleared, sounds as though it is cleared at least...